# iOS: Notify a WebService of location change (using Significant-Change Location Service)

Tags: ios, location, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an app that allows me to track the device's location, the idea is that the app notifies every few hours our servers of the current location so I can send relevant push notifications to the user.
This should work even if the app is not running (the app should be awakened by the OS).
I was reading the Location Awareness Programming Guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) and I think the Significant-Change Location Service would help me accomplish this, however the guide mentions this:

> it should do minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as querying the
>   network) that might prevent it from returning before the allocated
>   time expires.

If this is the case, I don't think I will be able to notify our servers of the location change.

I'm assuming this is possible because there are apps like "Find My Phone" that have to get the updated location of the devices every once in a while.

If this is not the right approach I would appreciate any pointers to info on what should I do to get this working.

Thanks

Comment: find my iphone app, is an apple app, they can use services that other apps cannot use. so dont compare witht that.

Comment: I meant it as an example, but obviously there are lots of similar apps. http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/12-apple-device-finder-apps-similar-to-find-my-iphone/